# Using htaccess to rewrite a get variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours but stumped. I am trying to rewrite the url with a get variable to make it seem like a file. I've tried many different answers I've seen to no avail. Is it possible that I don't have a certain setting turned on? Your help is greatly appreciated!!

I am trying to redirect
[www.site.com/products/?q=coconut](http://www.site.com/products/?q=coconut)
to
[www.site.com/products/coconut](http://www.site.com/products/coconut)

so far this code gives me a 500 error

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /products?q=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow dumb mistake on my part, but leaving this up just in case someone else is pulling their hair out. I had a faulty php code which lead to a 500 error.